# Updating Environment makes view re-render with all his States Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have an @Environment who store all share data for my views. One of my views use one of its variables to present a list with collapsable items. For make the list collapsable I use a @State whether is true or false expand the collapsable content, inside this list I want the user could delete its items so I made a function that remove item from the variable in the @Environment and update the view. The problem is that the State change to his default value and the Expanded list comback to be collapse. I would like to know how to preserve the previus states or maybe tell my views that only re-render the parts that actually changes.

This is my Environment object. All my views have acces to this.

```
class GlobalData:ObservableObject {
    @Published var SpoonData: [Item?] = []
    @Published var currentTab: Int = 0

    func deleteSpoonData(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        self.SpoonData.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }

    func addSpoonData(item: Item, itemList: Items){
       let exists = SpoonData.firstIndex(where: {$0?.ItemId == item.ItemId})
        var rt = item
        rt.ItemList = itemList

        if exists == nil {
            self.SpoonData.append(rt)
        }
    }
    func deleteProductFromItemList(product: Product, itemId: Int) {
        let fatherIndex = self.SpoonData.firstIndex { item -> Bool in
            item?.ItemId == itemId
        }

        let childIndex = (self.SpoonData[fatherIndex!]?.ItemList?.ItemList?.firstIndex(where: { productfiltered -> Bool in
            productfiltered?.EntryID == product.EntryID
        }))!

        print(self.SpoonData[fatherIndex!]?.ItemList?.ItemList![childIndex])
        self.SpoonData[fatherIndex!]?.ItemList?.ItemList!.remove(at: childIndex)

    }
}
```

This is the view that present the list.

```
    struct SpoonListItemView: View {

    private let viewModel: SpoonListItemViewModel
    @State private var isCollapsed: Bool =  false

    init(viewModel: SpoonListItemViewModel) {
           self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {

                    if self.viewModel.ItemType == 1 {
                        AsyncImage(url: viewModel.ItemImageUrl, size: CGSize(width: 45.0, height: 45.0), contentMode: .fit)
                            .clipShape(Rectangle())
                    } else {
                        AsyncImage(url: viewModel.ItemImageUrl, size: CGSize(width: 45.0, height: 45.0), contentMode: .fit)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("\(viewModel.ItemName)")
                            .font(.custom("NunitoSans-Bold", size: 14))
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        Text(viewModel.ItemType == 1 ? "Receta" : "Producto")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("textColor"))
                            .font(.custom("NunitoSans-Light", size: 12))
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }.frame(height: 50)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 24, bottom: 0, trailing: 24)).onTapGesture {
                        self.isCollapsed.toggle()
                }

            }
            if self.viewModel.ItemType == 1 {
                if self.isCollapsed {
                    SpoonListProductView(viewModel: SpoonListProductViewModel(items: self.viewModel.ItemList, father: self.viewModel.ItemId))
                }
            }
        }

        }
}

And this is the view that present the childs when is expanded

    struct SpoonListProductView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalData: GlobalData
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SpoonListProductViewModel
    @State private var isInEditingMode: Bool = false
    var fatherId: Int?

    init(viewModel: SpoonListProductViewModel) {
            self.viewModel = viewModel
       }

       var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(viewModel.dataSource) { vm in
                Group{
                    HStack {
                        SpoonProductView.init(viewModel: vm).onLongPressGesture {
                            self.isInEditingMode = true
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        if self.isInEditingMode {
                            Image(systemName: "trash.fill").foregroundColor(Color("textColor")).onTapGesture {
                                self.delete(vm: vm)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
            }

           }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))

       }

    func delete(vm: ProductViewModel) {
        //self.viewModel.ItemList?.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        self.globalData.deleteProductFromItemList(product: vm.product, itemId: self.viewModel.father!)
    }
}
```

This is The code for the List:

```
struct SpoonListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalData: GlobalData
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SpoonListViewModel
    var items: [Item?]

    init(items: [Item?] ) {
        self.items = items
        self.viewModel = SpoonListViewModel(items: self.items)
    }

    var body: some View {
        SpoonListItemsView(viewModel: viewModel.dataSource!)
    }
}
```

And this is its viewModel:

```
class SpoonListViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
     @Published var dataSource: SpoonListItemsViewModel? = nil
    var items: [Item?]

    init(items: [Item?]) {
        self.items = items
        self.dataSource =    SpoonListItemsViewModel(items: self.items as! [Item])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not `SpoonListItemView` but the view witch holds it. `@State` should be preserved between renders, but in this case, you have a `List` or `ForEach` of elements, in your (let's assume) `SpoonListView`. which re-renders the list, on each change. I think moving an `openIndex` state to the list, or higher level can be one solution.

Also, you can mask the event in `GlobalData` by overriding the synthesised with `let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()`, but that would mean you have to call in on other occasions manually. So, I would avoid that.

*PS: For better understanding could you add the code of the list as well?*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already updated my question and added the code for the list.

Answer (score 0):

If your Deployment Target is iOS14 and above, have you tried replacing `@ObservedObject` with `@StateObject` in `SpoonListView`? This will help in keeping the state, it will only be created once, even if the Model View instantiaton happens inside the View's body.